# Android build error "failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class" :Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Following this tutorial https://github.com/Vidyo/vidyo.io-connector-xamarin I downloaded the app without making any changes.

When I build the app, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class: Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/ITouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\vidyo.io-connector-xamarin-master\vidyo.io-connector-xamarin-master\VidyoConnector.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.java'.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Generator.CreateJavaSources(TaskLoggingHelper log, IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, String outputPath, String applicationJavaClass, String androidSdkPlatform, Boolean useSharedRuntime, Boolean generateOnCreateOverrides, Boolean hasExportReference) VidyoConnector.Android

What is the possible fix for this?

Comment: I download this sample , and also have issue when running project in android, so I suggest you can feecback this issue on this issue link:https://github.com/Vidyo/vidyo.io-connector-xamarin/issues

Answer (score 21):

That seems a problem with long path in windows. Put the project folder on the root, say C://yourproject. Then, clean your solution and build.

Comment: I'm using VS2022 and Maui and I had the same problem. This worked for me! Thanks @Lawrence.

Answer (score 11):

@LawrenceWlt is correct but I would like to add some more information.

Is is due to `Maximum Path Length Limitation`

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
> paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
> defined as 260 characters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

If you are on Windows 10, Version 1607 or later you can Enable Long Paths:

The registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD)` must exist and be set to 1.

The application manifest must also include the longPathAware element.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later

I got a similar error from Experimental Mobile Blazor Bindings:

https://github.com/xamarin/MobileBlazorBindings

> Failed to generate Java type for class:
> Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor
> due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find
> a part of the path
> 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\MobileBlazorBindings-master\samples\MobileBlazorBindingsXaminals\MobileBlazorBindingsXaminals.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java'.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost) at
> System.IO.File.Delete(String path) at
> Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String
> destination) at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.CreateJavaSources(IEnumerable`1
> javaTypes, TypeDefinitionCache
> cache)    MobileBlazorBindingsXaminals.Android

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to the Android projects's .csproj file fixed the issue for me:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\E</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It writes the intermediate Android files to a folder of your choice - obviously choose a really short one to avoid long paths!

Comment: Very handy to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution that hasn't been mentioned yet:  Create a Directory Junction and point it to your solution directory.  Place the junction at the root-level, then run the solution from there.

This approach will enable you to workaround the MAX_PATH issue without having to move your project or upgrade to Windows 10.

For example, let's say you store all your code in C:\dev, all your repos in C:\dev\repos, all your Git repos in C:\dev\repos\git, all your Xamarin Git repos in C:\dev\repos\git\xamarin, and all the mobile apps you've built for your largest client in C:\dev\repos\git\xamarin\isis (hey it's not my place to judge).  Your latest project can be found in C:\dev\repos\git\xamarin\isis\satellite-tracker\src, but you can't get it to build because the path is too long.

So we create a new directory, C:\J, which will hold this and any other junctions we create for this workaround on other projects.  Then open a command prompt as Administrator and navigate to C:\J.  Then enter the following command:

```
mklink /J SatTrack C:\dev\repos\git\xamarin\isis\satellite-tracker\src
```

Now you can access your solution file from C:\J\SatTrack.  If you open it from there, Visual Studio will use that path instead of the longer one and you should be fine after a clean/rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that works great is changing the build output folder in Android Project -> Properties -> Build -> Output path

Comment: This did not work for me.